# generate python classes from application/x-protobuf file

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have a python script that receives a application/x-protobuf file from youtube.
This part of the file

```
*youtubei#playerResponse
\862\94

yt_ad1\83
e~11200142,901816,936105,9407053,9407664,9407715,9408142,9410705,9412913,9415294,9416137,9417116,9417192,9417455,9418117,94182142\88\83
e~11200142,901816,936105,9407053,9407664,9407715,9408142,9410705,9412913,9415294,9416137,9417116,9417192,9417455,9418117,94182142\D6+
InnerTubeBuildLabelyoutube_20150727_RC2
InnerTubeChangelist99168778\83
e~11200142,901816,936105,9407053,9407664,9407715,9408142,9410705,9412913,9415294,9416137,9417116,9417192,9417455,9418117,94182142\88&
innertube.build.changelist99168778-
innertube.build.labelyoutube_20150727_RC2'
innertube.build.timestamp
1437996969E
!innertube.build.variants.checksum 47cbe83e1d9f5a44654ab7896473362e
innertube.client_name3!
innertube.client_version10.28z\BC\9A\EF\CA\DC\A2\80\C8 \E0](\A8F0\88\A48\98u@\B0\EAM\CD\CCL?U\CD\CCL?]\00\00@?`2h\E42p\C0>x\80\88\C4\90\98\A0\00\AD\00\00\00\00\B0\00\B8\00\C0\C8Ќ\D0\00\D8\E0\E8\C7\F0d\F8\00\80\90\00\98\00\C0\00\C8\A0\A8\00\B5\00\00\A0B\B8\00\D8\00\E0\00\E8\00\F0\F0\F8\80\00\88\00\90\00\B2ϭ\D3
\00\00 \C1\A2\DFޜ\00Z\AD
```

I want to generate  python classes from this file.
I used protoc to decode the file

```
cat binay_file | protoc --decode_raw > decoded_file
```

Then I used this command to generate the classes

```
protoc -I=/root --python_out=$DST_DIR /root/decoded_file
```

however this command always returns "Expected top-level statement (e.g. "message")." error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input to `protoc` is a `.proto` source file declaring the overall structure of the protocol. It looks like you're trying to use as input an actual message. This won't work -- these aren't the same thing.

There is no automated way to reverse-engineer a `.proto` file from a message instance, since an encoded message does not contain things like type names or field names and contains only limited information about actual field types. You can use the output of `--decode_raw` to make guesses about the original `.proto` file, but this is a reverse-engineering task that requires human analysis, not something that can be done by a program.